# Is there any hook triggered when a spring integration flow finishes in testing with the OnlyOnceTrigger?

Tags: spring, testing, spring-integration

In testing for projects with spring-integration, with the `OnlyOnceTrigger`, it is expected that a flow will finish soon. However I cannot find a way to determine when thus I have to use `Thread.sleep(n)` to wait for enough time, which is quite inefficient.

For example, with the following sample codes, how do I know the 4 integers polled are all printed out? Any suggestion with this issue?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class DemoApplication {

    Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(DemoApplication.class);

    @Bean
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    PollerSpec poller(){
        return Pollers.trigger(new OnlyOnceTrigger()).maxMessagesPerPoll(1);
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "input",
            poller = @Poller("poller"))
    public MessageSource<Integer[]> inbound(){
        return new MessageSource<Integer[]>() {
            public Message<Integer[]> receive() {
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Integer[]{1,2,3,4}).build();
            }
        };
    }

    @Splitter(inputChannel = "input", outputChannel = "output")
    public Integer[] split(Integer[] list){
        return list;
    }

    @Bean
    QueueChannel output(){
        return new QueueChannel(2);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "output",
            poller = @Poller(taskExecutor = "taskExecutor", fixedRate = "1", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public void markSms(int value) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a channel interceptor to the last channel in the flow to detect when the flow ends. See the [testing-samples](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/testing-examples) for other testing suggestions. Also [advanced-testing-samples](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/advanced-testing-examples) and the [Testing Support Appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/testing.html) in the reference manual.

Comment: But my expectation is that the "flow finished" event should only trigger after the last endpoint has consumed the message. Adding an interceptor to the last channel can only trigger the event before the endpoint right? Maybe advice-chain to the last endpoint is the solution but I don't know how to dynamically add it only in test.

Comment: Your expectations might be unreasonable; it's hard to say without an concrete example of the test you are trying to write. There is no standard "flow finished event"; extra configuration is required. Spring `Trigger`s don't work that way, they fire based on the configuration. If you edit your question with an example of what you are trying to achieve, someone might be kind enough to provide a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have edited my question with the sample codes attached.